# Do all Caffe2 projects have to be under caffe2 install folder?

Tags: caffe, caffe2

I've successfully installed Caffe2 on my TX2 with jetPack by NVIDIA.

I am trying to figure out if I could make a folder that's not under my caffe2 installation folder (where caffe2 is installed) and make a new cmake project.

How does one connect the libraries from that root caffe2 folder to execute in that folder that's not under the installation folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question.

If you want to replace a Caffe2 dependency (like a library) by a library that comes from your project, you can do that by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH accordingly.

Comment: Thanks - I've figured this out. I was confused on how to link with CMAKE. Appreciate the reply.